# App crashes when picking image

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using the below code for uploading image.

```
public async void btnAttachment_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Photos Not Supported", ":(Permission not granted to photos.", "OK");
        return;
    }

    _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

    if (_mediaFile == null)
        return;

    LocalPathLable.Text = _mediaFile.Path;

    FileImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        var stream = _mediaFile.GetStream();
        _mediaFile.Dispose();
        return stream;

    });
}
```

In this after selecting an image, the app crashes suddenly.

Comment: If your app crashes, please add stack traces and other relevant information.

Comment: add debugger and check in which line your application is crashing.

Comment: Your code works for me with Plugin.Media, Version=2.6.2.0 I assume that LocalPathLable is a label, FileImage is Image and _mediaFile is defined as member of the class

Answer (score 0):

I never found cross media plugins upload existing photo code to work. Instead I used dependency injection for implementing native gallery selections. Once you have the url you can stick it in an image view or inflate it in your native code as a bitmap or whatever. I actually pass back Model.Photo with the name and byte[] of the photo but it is up to you.

**PCL**

```cs
var x = await DependencyService.Get<IMedia>().UploadGallery();
```

**Android**

```cs
class Media_Android : Activity, IMedia
{
    public async Task<string> UploadGallery()
    {
            var activity = Forms.Context as MainActivity;

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.SetType("image/*");
            intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);


            var result = await activity.StartActivityForResultAsync(intent);

            if(result.Data != null)
            {
                Android.Net.Uri myUri = result.Data.Data;

                var getString = this.GetPathToImage(myUri);

                if (getString != null)
                {
                    return getString;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
    }
}

private string GetPathToImage(Android.Net.Uri uri)
{


        int currentapiVersion = (int)Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt; // Gets the Android version number for ex:- Lollipop 21-22, KitKat 19–20, JellyBean: 16-18.
        string path = "";
        // "KitKat 4.4(KitKat) and above compatible"
        if (currentapiVersion > (int)Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.JellyBeanMr2)
        {
            Android.Database.ICursor cursor1 = Forms.Context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            cursor1.MoveToFirst();
            string document_id = cursor1.GetString(0);
            if(document_id.Contains(":"))
            {
                document_id = document_id.Split(':')[1];
            }
            cursor1.Close(); //Extract the ID from the URI

            cursor1 = Forms.Context.ContentResolver.Query(
            Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + " = ? ", new System.String[] { document_id }, null);
            cursor1.MoveToFirst();
            path = cursor1.GetString(cursor1.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data));
            cursor1.Close(); //Query the device database, to get the Image based on the ID


        }



        //"JellyBean 4.1 - 4.3.1 (JellyBean) and below compatible"
        if (currentapiVersion <= (int)Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.JellyBeanMr2)
        {
            System.String[] projection = new System.String[] { Android.Provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns.Data };
            contentResolver = Forms.Context.ContentResolver;
            Android.Database.ICursor cursor = contentResolver.Query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.Count > 0)
            {
                cursor.MoveToFirst();
                int index = cursor.GetColumnIndex(Android.Provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns.Data);
                path = cursor.GetString(index);


            }
        }

        return path;

 }
```

**iOS**

It is much easier than Android just google.

Comment: Your code does not consider EXIF rotation and therefore the image you get could be rotated on some devices. CrossMedia plugin is working well for me. At least the last version. I had trouble on older versions though.

Comment: Agreed. Disclaimer* you cannot copy paste this solution you actually have to learn something about coding android/ios in conjunction with this starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the way I solved it was like this:

Please not that I was using the shared code and IOS only. Actually if you read the plugin readme it tells you to do this so read the Android part there if you are interested in the Android part.

1) In the IOS project go to info.plist
2) Open it with generic plist editor.
3) Add custom property
4) Select a cutom propert named "Privacy- Photo Library Usage Description"
5) Under value input a string that you want to display to the user when he/she gets asked whether they want to allow the app to access the photo library.

After I did this the app stopped crashing after I select a photo from the library. It asked me to give the app rights once and worked fine after that.